# how to get the file names stored in sd card in android

Tags: java, android, file, sd-card

i have a folder in sd card which contains several files.
now i need to get the names of that files.
can anybody have any idea how to get the file names stored in sd card?

any help will be appreciative.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) will give you a `File` corresponding to the SDCARD. Then you'll just have to use [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) methods.

That should be something like that :

```
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "yourpath");
for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
    if (f.isFile())
        String name = f.getName();
        // make something with the name
}
```

A little note of advice : from KitKat and above, this requires the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: Have you checked the source code of the two methods `list()` and `listFiles()`? There is a little difference between them. Interesting to know what the diff is.

Comment: @Martjin : internally, `listFiles` uses list to create a list of file names, and creates `File` objects. But as the OP wanted to have only files, I preferred using `listFiles`.

Comment: @ValentinRocher how to get the file path ? - file.getpath() ? or there another way?

Comment: You'll probably use getCanonicalPath() or something like that, just look at the File javadoc

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Return list of files from path. <FileName, FilePath>
 *
 * @param path - The path to directory with images
 * @return Files name and path all files in a directory, that have ext = "jpeg", "jpg","png", "bmp", "gif"  
 */
private List<String> getListOfFiles(String path) {

    File files = new File(path);

    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {

        private final List<String> exts = Arrays.asList("jpeg", "jpg",
                "png", "bmp", "gif");

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            String ext;
            String path = pathname.getPath();
            ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            return exts.contains(ext);
        }
    };

    final File [] filesFound = files.listFiles(filter);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (filesFound != null && filesFound.length > 0) {
        for (File file : filesFound) {
           list.add(file.getName());
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

This will give you the list of images in a folder. You can modify the code to get all files.

Answer (score 1):

In Android 5.0 Lollipop, I found that we need add the permission to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If not, we could not see any file in sdcard. I take an hour to find this!

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<String>nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
 File yourDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/myFolder");
 for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) 
 {
    if (f.isFile())
    {
       nameList.add(f.getName);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all files and folder from a specific path of FOLDER then use this code it will help you

```
String path="/mnt/sdcard/dcim";  //lets its your path to a FOLDER

String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file = new File(path) ;       
File list[] = file.listFiles();
  for(File f:list)
    {
       filename.add(f.getName());//add new files name in the list
     }
```