# get images' names in directory

Tags: android, image, imageview

How can I get only images' names in known directory.
Trying use this ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561217/how-to-get-the-file-names-stored-in-sd-card-in-android))

```
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "yourpath");
for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
    if (f.isFile())
        String name = f.getName();
        // make something with the name
}
```

but don't works.
How can I do this?

Comment: Filter for known filename extension conventions? But dont know if a method for such operation already might exist in some API. Wasnt there a default location where the images were saved at?

Comment: I have known only folder location and know, that in this folder are images with .jpg format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
            //getting SDcard root path
           File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath());
           getfile(root);
            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
                // getting file name

                System.out.println(fileList.get(i).getName());
    if (fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {
                    teSystem.out.println("This is Directory not an image");
                }



        }

// getfile(file) method

public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                    getfile(listFile[i]);

                } else {
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif"))

                    {
                        fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return fileList;
    }

hope it will help your purpose.
```

Comment: tried. See this "The method getfile(File) is undefined..."

Comment: @user2382720 i have edited my answer check it out now.

Comment: FYI: Since java 1.7 this recursive algorithm can be replaced by a `SimpleFileVisitor`. Inside the visitor there are methods to handle a file and a folder separately. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html) and [some example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68) using `Path`s